# XSL Problems Dealing with Sporadic and Repetitive Tags going to csv

Tags: xml, csv, xslt

I have the following XML file I am converting to csv, the problem is, the first data section is all string tags which I can skip if I need and the second section is a mix of string and int tags. I am able to get the data out, but there is a weird block of data on top I am unable to remove. The XML file is automatically generated so I cant change it.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <methodResponse><params><param><value>
        <struct>
            <member><name>columns</name><value>
                <array><data>
                    <value><string>id</string></value>
                    <value><string>scanTime</string></value>
                    <value><string>host</string></value>
                    <value><string>vuln</string></value>
                    <value><string>port</string></value>
                    <value><string>protocol</string></value>
                </data></array>
            </value></member>
            <member><name>table</name>
<value>
                <array><data>
      <value>
        <array><data>
            <value><int>1</int></value>
            <value><int>1414010812</int></value>
            <value><string>Host.5</string></value>
            <value><string>Vuln.6230</string></value>
            <value><int>500</int></value>
            <value><string>udp</string></value>
        </data></array>
    </value>
    <value>
        <array><data>
            <value><int>2</int></value>
            <value><int>1414010978</int></value>
            <value><string>Host.6</string></value>  
            <value><string>Vuln.1191</string></value>
            <value><int>22</int></value>
            <value><string>tcp</string></value>
        </data></array>
    </value>
    <value>
        <array><data>
            <value><int>3</int></value>
            <value><int>1414010978</int></value>
            <value><string>Host.6</string></value>
            <value><string>Vuln.30535</string></value>
            <value><int>22</int></value>
            <value><string>tcp</string></value>
        </data></array>
    </value>
    <value>
        <array><data>
            <value><int>4</int></value>
            <value><int>1414010978</int></value>
            <value><string>Host.6</string></value>
            <value><string>Vuln.78682</string></value>
            <value><int>22</int></value>
            <value><string>tcp</string></value>
        </data></array>
    </value>
            </data></array>
            </value></member>
        </struct>
</value>
    </param>
    </params>
    </methodResponse>

**my XSL 1.0 code below**

        <xsl:variable name="new-line" select="'
    '"/>
        <xsl:output method="text" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="no"/>
        <xsl:template match="value/array/data">
           <xsl:for-each select="//array/data">
                    <xsl:for-each select="value">
                             <xsl:value-of select="translate(*, $new-line,' ')"/>,
                             </xsl:for-each><br/>;
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:template>
    </xsl:stylesheet>
```

**my desired output**

```
    id,scanTime,host,vuln,port,protocol
    1,1414010812,Host.5,Vuln.6230,500,udp;
    2,1414010978,Host.6,Vuln.1191,22,tcp;
    3,1414010978,Host.6,Vuln.30535,22,tcp;
    4,1414010978,Host.6,Vuln.78682,22,tcp;
    5,1414010978,Host.6,Vuln.78683,22,tcp;
```

The problem is that it runs through the process and prints everything on one line with huge spaces before it prints my desired output. I have tried using other examples from this web site but i can't get any to match up.

Answer (score 0):

Consider `<xsl:strip-space>` to remove gap at top of output. However, remove the line break variable and use the entity `&#xa;` (`<br>` is an html tag) And since only `<member>` carries any text, run that template in stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="text" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="no"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="member">
        <xsl:for-each select="descendant::array[last()]/data/value">
             <xsl:value-of select="*"/> 
             <xsl:if test="position() != last()">,</xsl:if>                 
        </xsl:for-each>
        <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output

```
id,scanTime,host,vuln,port,protocol
1,1414010812,Host.5,Vuln.6230,500,udp
```

Comment: That works amazing for what i asked. I am very sorry I forgot to mention I have multiple records. In the table section there are multiple tables of array and data that hold multiple results, i cut it out so i didn't clutter the post, however it seems i made it harder.

Comment: Please update your post with actual XML of a few nodes to discern pattern.